# What would be a viable explanation for "destroyable knowledge"?

Tags: science-based, memory

In the game [Warframe](https://warframe.com/), we have blueprints which are "consumed" during the process of making a weapon / Warframe.

In some Chinese fantasy Kung Fu movies, a person caught illegally learning martial arts, i.e. stealing, from someone who has not agreed to teach him, can be punished by having his Kung Fu "banished" from him, making him no longer able to perform the skills.

In Dr Strange, at the post credits scene

> Mordo "rips" something (I assume it's "astral knowledge") from Jonathan causing him to become paralyzed again.

If "blueprints", "Kung Fu", "astral knowledge" are just knowledge that can be recalled at any time, and if brainwashing does not occur (We don't see Ordis [The aforementioned Kung Fu stealer.] or Jonathan suffer any memory loss.), what would be a (pseudo-)feasible explanation of this?

Comment: In Dr Strange, it isn't knowledge. It's actual power that is taken. The rest of the question stands, but that example is off-the-mark.

Comment: Generally in Kungfu movies depriving someone of their kungfu is usually accomplished by inflicting injury or harm to critical parts of the body. Thereafter, the person cannot perform kungfu. Sometimes the injuries can be cured, and the kungfu works again. @SRM is right, but this is more general than just in *Doctor Strange*.

Comment: @SRM It seemed as though Steven Strange mastered the mystic arts simply by reading and practicing and with the "guidance" of the Ancient One, but that no actual power was given externally to him (I assume the same is for Jonathan)?

Comment: I feel like the blueprint idea is quite different from the others. You'll need a wildly different process to consume a piece of paper in construction than to remove knowledge from a person.

Comment: @Woofas It's specifically pointed out in the movie that Jonathan's abilities were his alone; he developed them with the knowledge provided by (whatever the monastery was called) and was not granted anything other than that knowledge. He only achieved it because he had the potential to do so, and that was what was taken.

Answer (score 5):

### Using knowledge without permission is social taboo

I know this answer is on verge of "brainwashing" but if such conditioning happens on bigger scale, you do not even consider it as brainwashing techniques, rather than "common knowledge"

Examples:

- You wash your hands before you go eat. However, if you are from first world country, there is really small chance that your hands are *actually* dirty enough to cause any real problem. Yet still we all do it
- It is social taboo to go to the toilet which is not labeled your gender. Changing this rule in USA leads to loads of discussions

So, in same terms, it would be simply unthinkable to use knowledge you obtained without permission of your teacher. Imagine doing so would "kill" your social status. People reject to talk to you and even consider you being perverted for doing so.

That would practically mean, that almost no one would use knowledge they were not approved to

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the blueprints are a file with a working [digital rights management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_rights_management) system. It can only be copied onto DRM-compliant devices, and sending it to a [3D printer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_printing) or [CNC machine tool sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_control) a counter.

Such a system can be hacked or otherwise overcome, just ask the music industry, but many people in your setting might not be able to do it.

Comment: "working digital rights management system" is an oxymoron, ask any computer scientist.

Comment: @Aron is right. DRM only "works" on people that wouldn't really be that interested in copying illegally anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**This applies to the consumed blueprints, but not to the wiping of memory. Human memory and physical memory are totally different realms to work with.**

[Magnetic Core Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic-core_memory) is a form of information storage that is destroyed upon reading (called destructive readout). If you have blueprints stored with this kind of memory it won't be able to be used again unless intentionally re-saved.

**Now for my unrelated answer about human memory:**

In order to make human memory rendered removable, you could cause everyone to have a computer chip which every night as they go to sleep saves all of their memory and when they wake up loads it again to their brain. The benefit of this is that you may load more information onto this chip which in turn get's loaded onto their brain.

A corollary is that information can be removed using this same method.

Permission to make changes may be restricted to you and the government, which would allow information theft to be reversed by authorities. Unfortunately, it would undoubtedly be hackable which could cause mayhem from whoever cracks it open. It would potentially open up the possibility of a total change of person unless it was somehow only restricted to recent memory.